# "Following" or "The following"?

Tags: articles

For a leading sentence before a list of items to be presented in a slide deck what is correct?

`Following items....`

or

`The following items...`

Use of word "following" is definitively identifying the items being referred so do we still need to use "the"?

Comment: Definitely "The following items", I'd say.

Comment: Note that neither example is a "sentence".

Comment: @HotLicks I used ellipsis to say that there is something after those words that forms a complete sentence. I did not think that exact words of those sentences are relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, I would appreciate a comment explaining why they downvoted it?

Comment: Following items in the word list I find iterate.

Answer (score -2):

The following items, as it is more formal oppose to slang like. Following items could be used mid-sentence but I would use "The following items"

Comment: [*Slang*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slang) is “very informal usage in vocabulary and idiom that is characteristically more metaphorical, playful, elliptical, vivid, and ephemeral than ordinary language”. Neither "fhe following items" nor "following items" qualifies as slang.

Comment: But if you think about it as I reader I would picture an informal conversation following items like careless

Comment: I can't think of a time where I would ever be okay hearing "Following items", not because it's slang (which I don't agree it is), but because it's not grammatically correct.